# How to add Command to ListBox.ItemTemplate

Tags: xaml, binding, command

I have a WPF application using MVVM.

This code is from my ResourceDictionary.xaml

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="LogListTemplate">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LogList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalListBoxItem}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource ErrorBorders}">
                        <StackPanel ToolTip="{Binding Details}" Width="250">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <Button Command="{Binding AddToTempDtdFileCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Details}" Content="Ignore" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

When I click on Button, the command does not execute. Testing confirms this is because my Button lives within a ListBox.

My problem is I can't move my button out of the ListBox for 2 reasons.

```
1. Asthetics/UI (the button has belong with the information)  
2. Binding to the LogList is done from within the ListBox.ItemTemplate
```

Does any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the command is defined in the `ViewModel` you can reach it by using `RelativeSource`. `RelativeSource` can find an ancestor (which is your `View`) so you can use its `DataContext` (your `ViewModel`).

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.AddToTempDtdFileCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourViewClass}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Details}" Content="Ignore" />
```